# O365 auto forward broke after changing the forwarding address

Tags: email, smtp, office365, exchangewebservices

So I've had a catchall 365 mailbox setup for a while that forwards to my Gmail account.

Earlier today I ended up with a load of spam to my domain which was clogging up my Gmail. I have an old personal Gmail that gets a lot of spam anyway so I decided to change the fwd to that one while I'm out until I get home to sort the filter out.

However when I changed the address. I now get bounce back emails in o365 saying my organisations outbound forward filter is at fault. And they don't hit the gmail

I've checked the exchange settings and forwarding is still enabled within the rule as always. Even tried setting it back to the original Gmail and I get the same issue?

The account is through GoDaddy. But in the admin centre the forward box shows the correct address.

Anyone have any other ideas? All that's changed was the forwarding address and it's been working fine for over a year now.

Comment: fyi Stack Overflow is the wrong place for such a question (it's specifically for *programming* q&a). The [tag:email] tag description says "Questions about configuration of mail servers belong on Server Fault." So... maybe post on [sf]?